# How to save links of online lectures in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

I want to save some information of an online lecture such as the link on evernote.

For example, I would like to save the [lecture](http://www.aicdesign.org/scnotes/2010notes/lect2up330_(100328).pdf) in evernote.

Here is what I did:

1. Select the title: "LECTURE 330 – HIGH SPEED COMPARATORS LECTURE ORGANIZATION"
2. Choose "windows + A" from keyboard

Below is what it appears in evernote. The problem is that there is no link to the lecture at all. I would like to save the link so I can click the link when necessary.

Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't make much sense. You provided a link to PDF, so if you open a PDF select text, you won't ever get any link. Better describe what do you the note to contain.

Comment: Hi, should it save the link containing the PDF file such as below?
http://www.aicdesign.org/scnotes/2010notes/lect2up330_(100328).pdf